# How to make git add by patch by default

Tags: git

How can I make it so that executing `git add` will include the `-p` flag by default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to change defaults of commands in git. You can add your own alias though. For instance, I like to use this one:

```
git config --global alias.patch 'add -p'

# git add -p file.txt
git patch file.txt
```